# Trying to get View Class methods without import

Tags: java, android, view

I have been coming up across a problem that I have been trying to figure for about a week now. I am trying to use the `onDraw` method from the `View` class. Problem is, in my `Java` class, I have already something imported and I dont know how to get the `View` classes methods beacuse Java dosent allow to extend multiple classes. I have been looking at other posts, and I have tried there solutions, but in *my senario*, almost all solutions **dont work** . Any **other** solutions?

Java Class:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity /*Cant get rid of this import*/ {
//Cant import View because something is already imported
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tw = findViewById(R.id.text2);
    //Tried using View.onDraw(canvas), gives me error
}
//Will not work
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}


}
```

Comment: Create a separate View class and pass that view to setContentView.

Comment: @Prafulla Malviya I dont know how to pass "that" view. I know the method, but i dont really know what your talking about. Could you show me with code? Thanks.

Comment: give me 5 min. i'll write sample code for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look and accept suggestion if you like :)

```
/**
 * Created by Prafulla Malviya on 2/25/2018.
 * Time : 2.38 AM India
 */
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
        //init();
        //initView();
    }
}


package com.abhaya_foundation.abhayango;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Prafulla Malviya on 2/25/2018.
 * Time : 2.38 AM India
 */

public class MyView extends View {
    private Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // create the Paint and set its color
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 100, paint);
    }

}
```

Or you can add

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
```

In your activity xml and pass the instance of MyView to them.

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
        FrameLayout view  = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_1);
        view.addView(myView);
```

Comment: Great thanks, i am testing the code but im pretty sure i need to keep setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  beacuse that is the xml file.